# strtok_r() segfaults every time I call it, even in simple situations

Tags: c, strtok

I've read the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) for strtok_r and I'm relatively sure I'm using it correctly, but it segfaults every time.

So I decided to write a quick test program and discovered that this also segfaults:

```
//This define probably not necessary
//POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined as 200809L on my system
//It still doesn't work even with this define though..
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[255];
    char* token;
    char** saveptr;

    memset(input, 0, sizeof(char) * 255);
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    token = strtok_r(input, ":", saveptr);
}
```

The traceback from valgrind:

```
==15796== Command: ./a.out
==15796== 
==15796== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==15796==    at 0x4EDABA4: strtok_r (strtok_r.c:73)
==15796==    by 0x10878B: main (in /home/pluh/a.out)
==15796== 
==15796== Invalid write of size 8
==15796==    at 0x4EDABA4: strtok_r (strtok_r.c:73)
==15796==    by 0x10878B: main (in /home/pluh/a.out)
==15796==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==15796== 
==15796== 
==15796== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
```

I only put "test" in stdin, so I know it didn't overflow. Am I doing something wrong here? This is the most simple usage scenario I could think of and it still breaks.

Comment: `saveptr` is uninitialized. You should pass a pointer to `char*` to let the `strtop_r` return the value of `saveptr`, not an uninitialized `char **` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[255];
    char* token;
    char* saveptr;

    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    token = strtok_r(input, ":", &saveptr);

    printf("%s, %s\n",token,saveptr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I should have realized that strtok_r was going to modify the pointer and therefore I had to pass it by reference not by value. It's been a long day..

Comment: The functions that may return an address by means of a parameter needs the behaiour I indicated here. If a function shall retrieve an `int`, for example `i`, by means the parameter you have to pass to the function &i, obviously if the function should retrieve e pointer you shall to declare a pointer (for example char *p) and pass to the function &p.